# NoReverseMatch with arguments '(",)' in Django

Tags: python, html, django, web-applications, pycharm

I keep getting the NoReverseMatch error although I have checked numerous times to see if I have entered the code as instructed, and it seems I did, yet the webpage won't load properly. Because I have a few files and I don't know which one has the error (it should be urls.py but I just don't see where the error is located) I will post a link to my GitHub repository where I have uploaded all relevant files and a screenshot of the error message I've been getting. Sorry for not posting any code but I think it would make it very messy posting all the code here. Also, I saw a lot of similar questions but none of them solved my problem and none of them are with these exact arguments. This is where I think the error occurs (`base.html`):

```
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a>
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a>
</p>

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

Traceback:

Comment: Please paste the relevant code into your question here.

Comment: @voodoo-burger done, this should be where the error happens.

Comment: that is not it. The error is happening during the rendering of a template, probably `base.html` that is not in the repo you linked, but it is hard to tell because you cut off the image with the stack trace. Please post the contents of that template here and paste the FULL stack trace here as well.

Comment: in the future, please paste all the relevant files and stack traces in your post from the start. People will not be inclined to help you if you just give them a link to an external site and provide an image of stack trace.

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up. I added `base.html` code to the question and also a full image of the traceback.

Comment: You need to *copy and paste* the FULL stack trace, not provide it as an image. There is a "Switch to copy and paste view" link you can click to get a properly formatted stack trace you can paste here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really provided enough information, but from what I can tell you have a place in a template where you are using `{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' %}` without the `topic_id` argument, or where the `topic_id` variable is not set in the template.

Comment: I did include the `topic_id` argument everywhere, but I made a typo and wrote  `topic ` instead of  `topic_id `.

Comment: @DjoleRkc glad you got it fixed :)